# Add javascript script only when class is on hover

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, css-selectors, dom-events

I have this javascript that outputs an action to the elements on `class="link_mainhub"`

```
<script>
const el = document.querySelector('.link_mainhub')
const fx = new TextScramble(el)

let counter = 0
const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
    setTimeout(next, 800)
  })
  counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
}

next()
</script>
```

However, I just want to run the script whenever `class="link_mainhub"` is hovered.

I tried changing the `const el = document.querySelector('.link_mainhub')` to `const el = document.querySelector('.link_mainhub:hover')` but it didn't work.

How can I reproduce the script only when my class is being hovered?

Thanks.

Comment: [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)?

Comment: `$( yourClass ).mouseover(function() {
  //your stuff here
})`

Comment: @ScottWeaver I don't see where he says he's using jQuery?

Comment: squint your eyes and look really hard and you'll see it

Comment: It was incorrectly added as a tag to represent the vanilla javascript querySelector selector. However, jQuery uses querySelector as its underlying function, and I edited out jquery-selector for the more appropriate css-selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add eventListener of Mouseover to the element.
`el.addEventListener('mouseOver', next)`

Comment: Hi, I've added the event listener and now it starts the animation only when I mouseover the class, however, when I do `mouseout`, the animation continues playing.

Comment: Any way to stop animation on `mouseout`?

Comment: Okay. Then may mouseOver isn't the event you need. Try mouseEnter

Comment: Only if you create a function for that. and call the eventListener ```mouseOut``` on the element